# .htaccess redirection to specific url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I moved my site from blog.abc.com to www.abc.com

I want to redirect every request made to blog.abc.com to abc.com

For example:

If blog.abc.com/example.html is requested, it should redirect to www.abc.com/example.html, how can I do it via .htaccess only?

Comment: Has blog.abc.com its own vhost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put this code in your htaccess (in `blog.abc.com` root folder)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using mod_rewrite you could do it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCondition %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

or if blog.example.com has its own vhost you could also use mod_alias:

```
Redirect / http://example.com/
```